# Flutter, Dart: How to Programmatically Set Case Value in Switch Statement

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement, case

I am trying to programmatically set a case value in a switch statement.

I created a test variable firstYAxisValue

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getYAxisValues(minimum);
  }

    void getYAxisValues(int number) {
    firstYAxisValue = int.parse(closingPrices[widget.selectedCrypto][number]);
  }
```

and use it in a switch statement

```
switch (value.toInt()) {
              case 2:
                return 'SEPT';
              case firstYAxisValue:
                return '';
            }
```

but I receive an error saying "Case expressions must be constant." with regards to firstYAxisValue. So is it even possible to do this programmatically?

Comment: A `switch` statement is inappropriate for this kind of usage.  Use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin is correct. As the error stated: Case expressions must be (compile-time) constants, meaning you can not dynamically assign a variable as a switch case.

Comment: Thank you both I will use an if statement instead :)